# How to pass value between two classes

Tags: java, android, android-context

For example:
**Here**   **Variable in class A**

```
public class A{
    public String aClassVar="hello";
    }
```

**Using it in Class B**

```
A obj=new A();
String inBClass=obj.aClassVar;
```

but what about the other way around? How do I change String aClassVar from Class B? Can I pass Context from A to B constructor and then call `aContext.aClassVar = ...`?

Comment: Not nearly enough info here... How exactly is Android involved in this?

Comment: make the `aClassVar` as static type. it will solve your problem.

Comment: You should read some articles about object-oriented programming. Public non-final fields violate encapsulation. Use setters and getters instead.

Comment: @ZahidulIslam Yes... but it will introduce a singleton anti-pattern to the code. It would also need to be `final`. Mutable globals are a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private String myField; //"private" means access to this is restricted

    public String getMyField()
    {
         //include validation, logic, logging or whatever you like here
        return this.myField;
    }
    public void setMyField(String value)
    {
         //include more logic
         this.myField = value;
    }
}
```

Search Android getter and setter, you will have tons of links.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, String is Immutable so you can not change the value of it , you can only assign its value into other string etc. Secondly static is used to access things globally throughout the program.

Comment: But what about accessing the value of class A in class B?

Comment: Through various ways you can access, by creating object, static, or by declaring string directly under the class .This will be accessible in all method.

Answer (score -1):

Define `aClassVar` as a static variable, then

```
A obj=new A();
obj.aClassVar="new string";
```

Comment: Why do you want to make the variable `static` and then use a useless object reference on it?

Answer (score -1):

make `aClassVar` as static and use following code.

```
A objA=new A(); 
objA.aClassVar="new value";
```

or else use `getter` and `setter` method to change the values.

Comment: Why do you want to make the variable `static` and then use a useless object reference on it?